# ¿Cómo puedo hacer git pull después de un cambio en la historia en el remoto?

Tags: git, git-push

Si otro desarrollador hizo un cambio en la historia de `git` y luego hizo `git push -f`, `git pull` no me funciona.

¿Cómo puedo traer los cambios del remoto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Traducido de [git pull after forced update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813888/920295)

El primer paso es recibir todos los commits que están en el remoto, para eso hacé

```
git fetch
```

Asumo que estamos hablando de `master`. Si no, reemplazá `master` por el nombre de la branch con la que estés trabajando.

### Reset

Para apuntar las branches locales al mismo commit que está en el remoto, tenés que usar `git reset`.

#### Si no te importa perder tus cambios locales:

```
git reset origin/master --hard
```

Esto va a deshacer todos tus cambios y traer lo mismo que está en el remoto. A partir de ahora, `git push` y `git pull` van a funcionar como siempre.

#### Si querés mantener tus cambios locales:

En vez de un hard reset, hacé un soft reset

```
git reset origin/master --soft
```

Se pueden aplicar tus commits locales arriba de lo que está en el remoto usando `git rebase`

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Esto va a ejecutar un `rebase` en modo interactivo, donde podés elegir cómo aplicar tus commits locales que no están en el remoto arriba del `HEAD` actual.

Si los cambios en la historia borraron algún commit que vos tenés local, van a aparecer como commits pendientes de aplicar de vuelta. Si no querés que se apliquen, vas a tener que borrarlos como parte del rebase.

Usá `git command --help` para más detalles y ejemplos de cómo aplicar cualquiera de estos comandos.